# Show that the restricted algebra is also an algebra (worded better in the body)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $\mathfrak{U} \subset \mathfrak{B}(X)$ is a field. Let $S\in \mathfrak{U}$. Define:
>
> $$\mathfrak{U}|_S = \left\{A\cap S: A \in \mathfrak{U}\right\}\subset \mathfrak{B}(S)$$
>
> Show that $\mathfrak{U}|_S$ is a field in $\mathfrak{B}(S)$.

Proof:
    If we take $A,B \in \mathfrak{U}|_S$, we know that each of these can be written as $A'\cap S$ and $B'\cap S$, respectively. Using these two sets I will show the closure properties:
    $$A\cup B = \left(A'\cap S\right) \cup \left(B'\cap S\right)=S\cap \left(A'\cup B'\right)$$
    We have that $\mathfrak{U}$ is an algebra and so $A' \cup B'$ is in $\mathfrak{U}$, therefore $S \cap \left(A' \cap B'\right) \in \mathfrak{U}|_S$. Therefore $\mathfrak{U}|_S$ is closed under unions.
    $$A \cap B = \left(A' \cap S \right) \cap \left(B' \cap S\right) = \left(A'\cap B'\right) \cap S$$
    Similar to above we know that $A' \cap B'$ is in $\mathfrak{U}$ and so $\left(A' \cap B'\right)\cap S$ is in $\mathfrak{U}|_S$. This shows closure for intersections.\
    Lastly we have complements. Taking $A = A' \cap S$, we can take the complement of A in S:
    $$S\backslash A = S\backslash \left(A'\cap S\right) = A^c \cap S $$
    We know that $A^c \in \mathfrak{U}$ and so the intersection with S is in $\mathfrak{U}|_S$. This shows all the necessary closure properties so it is in algebra.

Is this proof sufficient? It seems way too simple to be the right way to go about this. Basically all I did was use the definition of the restricted algebra's elements and some set theory equivalences.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good!  Note that you don't actually have to check both unions and intersections, since you can build intersections from unions and complements (or unions from intersections and complements) by de Morgan.  Also, depending on your definitions, you may need to also check that $S\in \mathfrak{U}|_S$ and $\emptyset\in\mathfrak{U}|_S$ (though actually these are automatic if you know $\mathfrak{U}|_S$ is nonempty and closed under unions and complements).

Comment: Thank you! I will include the proof that $S\in \mathfrak{U}|S$ and so is the empty set. Those should be as easy as knowing that since $X\in\mathfrak{U}$ (by definition) then the intersection with X and S is S. Similarly for the empty set.